# how can print report in report builder 7.04 from calc tab- delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, reportbuilder

we are company use software which use report builder for report we need after print preview  execute print it directly without need to press print button , we  create code from calc tab in report Print form  create **event** but we cant find print method for print, any help

Comment: To actually print the report in code, try `Report.DeviceType := 'Printer'; Report.Print;`

Comment: Report.Print is not exist

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's happening for you, but for me `Report.Print` is defined in my 7.04 ppReport.pas. (With "Report" being the name of your TppReport component)

Comment: we use calc dialog from report design  for modify report not Delphi IDE.